# How do that the method of validation uniqueness not accept case sensitive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following problem. I have the model with the following validation

```
 validates :company, presence:true,
                      uniqueness: true,
                      format: /^([a-zA-z]+\s?){1,}$
```

if in the database there is stored a company with the value "Nevada" and after I add a new company with the value "nevada" that validation passes because "Nevada" is not than same that "nevada". How can I do for that the validation not accept case sensitive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dfine if it checks for case sensitive

```
   validates :company, presence:true,
                      uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false},
                      format: /^([a-zA-z]+\s?){1,}$
```

Check also [rails unique validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness)

Comment: Thanks Nermin. I worked perfect . I need case_sensitive: false

Comment: Could you change the answer to case_sensitive: false